# Extend generic class to be extended again in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to make generic component system in typescript. I created basic component with generic typed state:

```
    class Component<TState>{
        state: TState;
    
        public updateState(properties: Partial<TState>) {
            this.state = { ...this.state, ...properties };
        }
    }
```

I created a second component based on the basic component. I want to extend this component, so I tried something like this (This is not working.)

```
class FirstStateType {
    a: string;
}

class FirstComponent<TState extends FirstStateType> extends Component<TState extends FirstStateType> {
    init() {
        this.state.a = "1";
    }

    public FirstComponentMethod() {
        this.updateState({ a: "c" });
    }
}
```

I want to create a second component extension first component.

```
class SecondStateType extends FirstStateType {
    b: string;
}

class SecondComponent extends FirstComponent<SecondStateType> {
    init() {
        this.state.a = "a";
        this.state.b = "b";
    }

    public SecondComponentMethod() {
        this.FirstComponentMethod();
        this.updateState({ a: "c", b: "d" });
    }
}
```

The problem is: I want to full access to FirstStateType in the first component and then full access with extension in SecondComponent. How can I handle this?

For Example, when I tried this:

```
class FirstComponent<TState extends FirstStateType> extends Component<TState>
```

The FirstComponent state has not correct type. "(TS) Argument of type '{ a: "c"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<TState>'."

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbADvAdgUzQFwDwBUBlbMbDAPgG8BYAKGgeghLIC5oiWMBuOux6MgCuAIxABLYNCHIAJqQzEFABQBO8ZBlXZxGCAApk6zdt0R2ysKbAgCSsuQCU0GvQGNsAC3EQAdMwVoAF4XaF9wrx9-LgAaMPCjDS0dPWgAX143BjS6HNo6UEgYADFxVWZ7DHwAT00XfkYwdmZVcTQAc0y8gvAoaFLy7AQUdCw8TkCMAA8yNFkSsoquGs1yaGnZ%20bgkVEwcOy411wE28Wx9Z2P3Bki-ALJfMGDoACIARhfMgW6swVEJKQDZjDXZjACyGC88FkF3qvwEt18MnkZEqaiSpj0%20ko0Car2AL3Sji%20jDyP0KfUIGGA6FklRWGHWMywWyB2HptUZVwYIma2FaHS6fFoFJgVJpcxBoxwTM2C0GUr2eHFtI5qzhJzQZ1h3PciPuGEezxeYE%20DWu%20q4vhExpEZt%20PwEwjEkmgKslO2l2AhUJhl3Neu8fjZivBkM80IuJItQaRcgUaOMyTM2Nx7BeBLivNeskJaWJAbJQA)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please provide an **example** of the kind of access you're trying to use in `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` and copy-and-paste the errors, if any, you're receiving.

Comment: Also, the code you've provided has multiple errors even without trying to access anything: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WP7kJm). Please update the code to be a [mre] that doesn't have errors other than the ones you're asking about.